# How to get all rows stored in the `room` library using `Async Task`?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using `room` library with `android`. When I insert something in the database I get data for current running application, but when I restart the application, there is nothing in the screen. How to get previous stored data `without using LiveData` ?

Comment: This entirely depends on your code and what you are doing, as well as personal preference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking forward to get previous data, the following [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/)  might help you. But this really depends on your implementation.

> How to get previous stored data without using LiveData ?
>   How to get all rows stored in the `room` library using `Async Task`?

**Explanation**:

In Your Dao include the following code:

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    List<CustomObject> getAll();
```

In your Repository class include this snippet:

```
 public List<CustomObject> getAll() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    return new getAllAsyncTask(mCustomObjectDao).execute().get();
}

private static class getAllAsyncTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<CustomObject>> {

    private CustomObjectDao mAsyncTaskDao;
    List<CustomObject> a;

    getAllAsyncTask(CustomObjectDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<CustomObject> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return mAsyncTaskDao.getAll();
    }
}
```